# How to assign .editorconfig to a Visual Studio 2019 C++ solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

I am editing a VS solution that has a different coding style than the one I normally use. I found in the docs that VS 2019 supports [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019

I created `.editorconfig` file in the root of my solution:

[image]

I put this in the file:

```
root = true

[*.{cpp,hpp,h}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

I then went to the solution, right clicked the solution `Botcraft` in the solution explorer, selected *Add an existing item...* and added the aforementioned file. I can now see the item in the solution:

[image]

However, when I write `if(true)` and press enter, I still get two spaces as per my VS settings instead of four as per the editorconfig settings.

How to link `.editorconfig` to visual studio solution and make it respect the settings inside?

Comment: Just use `Add existing items` option for it

Comment: I did that exactly, it is said after the code block in my question.

Comment: I think it's bad to add your `.editorconfig` there. You should add it to each project you need and it will work when you hit `Ctrl + K Ctrl + D` in a file in that project.

Comment: Is the .editorconfig file in a folder above the source code? From your screenshot it looks like you are using cmake and likely your project folder doesn't contain the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditorConfig files [are only applied to the directory they are in and its sub-directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019#file-hierarchy-and-precedence) you need to put the file in the same folder as your source code (or a folder above it) not in the same folder as your solution/project files.

Comment: This was the problem, the source is above the solution dir in a diferent folder.